# Date Inversion in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula

I have a script that copies data from other workbooks and pastes it on another one for consolidation purposes. This report should show dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

My issue is that the workbook from where I bring the dates comes from SAP, with dots (.) instead of dashes (/). If I throw a replace to the column on this file, and then on the consolidation file I apply an Xlookup with a reference on this SAP extracted file the month and day get reversed.

Right now the bigger issue I have is that one of the dates is 12 of February (12.02.2021), and it turns into 2 of December (02.12.2021)

[image: This is the consolidation file]

[image: This is the zamsoct02 file I use to extract the dates, notice the format]

I have seen several options, however I was thinking that the xlookup plus a replace would be enough.
I have guided myself mostly from here:

https://www.macroption.com/excel-reverse-date/

Comment: let's say the date is in cell P2. you can use an extra column and rebuild your (un)inverted date using =date(year(P2),day(P2),month(P2)) or with substrings =date(right(P2,4),left(P2,2),mid(P2,4,2)). if you do this inversion in the script that brings the data, you can avoid this extra column

Comment: *I have a script that copies data from other workbooks*. You need to change that script so it will output the dates to Excel as "real dates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your script, have a step that converts your German formatted SAP *text* dates to true *Date* values like this:

```vb
TextDate = "12.02.2021"
TrueDate = DateValue(Replace(TextDate, ".", "-"))

' TrueDate -> 2021-02-12
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for the idea. How could I apply it to the column where the dates are located?

Comment: You will either need an extra column to hold the converted values, or - better - modify your script where you import/copy the original data.

Comment: Thank you! I actually managed to do it with this